# How to know if an email was actually sent (using flutter_email_sender)

Tags: flutter, dart, email, widget

I am using flutter_email_sender. My app has a screen where the user may input information like his or her name, and then click on a TextButton that redirects them to the email app in their phone (like Gmail) where a pre-written message using the information they inputted previously is already at the body of the email. **My issue is:**

Once the user sends the email and is redirected back to my app, I want to display a dialog that says something along the lines of "Your email has been successfully sent!". To do that, I simply added a dialog after the async function for flutter_email_sender is called. The problem is that, if the user does not send the email and instead simply goes back to the app, because the call to the function was successful, the success dialog still appears. But the person *didn't* send the email, so it shouldn't appear. Is there a way for me to track if the user *actually* sent the email and only display the dialog then?

Like I said above, I simply returned an AlertDialog after the function is called...

```
await FlutterEmailSender.send(email);
Future<void> showSuccessDialog() async {
return showDialog(
  context: context,
  barrierDismissible: false, 
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: const Text('Success!!'),
      content: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: ListBody(
          children: [
            const Text('Your email has been sent.'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      actions: [
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          }, 
          child: const Text('Ok'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
);
}
showSuccessDialog();
```

...But this causes the success dialog to appear even if the person hasn't actually sent the email, as long as the function successfully redirected them to the email app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this is not possible. `FlutterEmailSender.send()` completes with a `void`, so there is no information available to the caller.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up giving up and simply adding a dialog with a rather vague message, as to avoid the problem :'.) Thanks for the answer!